# How can i use Linaria with NextJS?

Tags: next.js, css-in-js

I want to use Linaria library(https://github.com/callstack/linaria) with nextJS.
Now, I implemented according to the document. But occurred the next error.

> Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom . Please move all global CSS imports to pages/_app.js.
>   Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/css-global

I understood this error. But I wondered. How can I use Linaria with NextJS?

- .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel", "linaria/babel"],
}
```

- next.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 1000,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    };
    return config;
  },

  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.tsx$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "linaria/loader",
          options: {
            sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a recent linaria [issue](https://github.com/callstack/linaria/issues/318) on this topic. It seems people are finding success with the following `next.config.js` config:

```js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS({
  webpack(config) {
    // retrieve the rule without knowing its order
    const jsLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => rule.test instanceof RegExp && rule.test.test('.js')
    );
    const linariaLoader = {
      loader: 'linaria/loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
      },
    };
    if (Array.isArray(jsLoaderRule.use)) {
      jsLoaderRule.use.push(linariaLoader);
    } else {
      jsLoaderRule.use = [jsLoaderRule.use, linariaLoader];
    }
    return config;
  },
});
```